# Android 6.0 - how to update rooted and tweaked MotoG 2015

Tags: root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, twrp, motorola-moto-g3

Recently I got a notification update to version 24.71.2.en.eu. When I tried to install it I received error:

```
mount point :/system 
location: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system , 
file system type: ext4script 
aborted: Package expects build fingerprint of 
motorola/osprey_reteu_2gb/osprey_u2:6.0/MPI24.65-33/36:user/release-keys or 
motorola/osprey_reteu_2gb/osprey_u2:6.0.1/MPI24.107-55-2/2:user/release-keys; 
this device has 
Motorola/omni_osprey/osprey:5.1.1/LYZ28N/sultan04050349:userdebug/test-keys.
Proces Updater terminated with error: 7
I:Legacy property environment disabled.
Error while installing zip '@/cache/recovery/block.map'
Stopped executing script
```

- **Device:** Lenovo/Motorola Moto G 3 2015 (osprey) XT1541
- **Current OS version:** 24.41.33.osprey_reteu_2gb.reteu.en.EU reteu
- **Compilation no:** MPI24.65-33
- **Root:** Beta-SuperSU-v2.76-3-20160630161323 (replaced unlocked_logo to
  remove unlocked warning)
- **Recovery:** TWRP 3.0.2-r1
- **Xposed version:** 86-sdk23

I know that there were many questions about updating rooted device and every answer provided a solution to flash stock system, recovery and boot images but what I want is to avoid reinstalling all software and starting from clean Android only just to install one update. I even found a solution to do that on rooted device but I did more: installed Xposed and removed unlocked warning.

What is the easiest procedure to install this update without loosing all data, apps and settings?

Comment: Wait for a package flashable from custom recovery. Those might appear on XDA-Developers and other places.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the installer is expecting the current build to be that of their retail ROM. Your method of rooting has been specifically marked for debug purposes (aka: rooted) and it doesn't want to continue.

Honestly if you want updates and support, either unroot your device or go to a custom ROM. As for keeping your stuff, use Titanium Backup to make a copy of all your stuff. You can restore it later if you go down the custom ROM route

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already have cyanogenmod on my second smartphone and I must say that updating is also problematic. Developers of custom ROMs often require to wipe all data and perform a clean flash before reporting any issues. MotoG3 is a phone with almost untouched Android so without root and Xposed offers very basic functionality.

Comment: Running CM(12,13,14) on Osprey since a year ago and there's nothing problematic here.